# Using jQuery checking if multiple checkboxes are checked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, switch-statement

Hello I'm wondering if it's possible to use jQuery to check if checkboxes are checked in a smart way, let's say that we use a switch case with a bunch of input fields, as an example I got 5 checkboxes.
Company, name, username, age, password.
And if you check Company, I can run my code.

I want to do this in the smartest way as possible in jQuery, let's say I want something like this in pseudo

```
switch(checkboxarray?) {

    case Company: 
    document.write("Company: INPUT FIELD");
    break;

}
```

I've looked into this but I've only found solutions that provide a function for one checkbox

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#messageVisibilityCheckbox').change(
        function () {
            if ($('#messageVisibilityCheckbox').is(':checked')) {
                alert('is checked'); //document.write("Company: INPUT FIELD);
            }  
            else {

            }
    });
});
</script>
```

and the HTML:

```
sinput type="checkbox" id="messageVisibilityCheckbox" name="messageVisibilityCheckbox"/>
```

so instead of creating a bunch of functions, I want to create one function with a switch case or something equal were I can just add a few lines for each checkbox.
The reason why I need this is because I'll have like 30 checkboxes and half of them requires an extra input field, any help or source is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear and your pseudo-code is not helping to clear anything up. Before you do anything in "the smartest way possible", try to do it *at all*. And you don't really need jQuery for this, you should be able to solve it without.

Comment: Thank you for your opinion, I've fixed it now so it should be easier to understand!

Comment: Definitely much better!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could group multiple individual HTML elements under the same parent and use [jQuery's event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Example

```js
$(function() {
    $('#allCheckboxes').on("change", ":checkbox", function () {
        if (this.checked) {
            console.log(this.id + ' is checked');
        } else {
            console.log(this.id + ' is unchecked');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="allCheckboxes">
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox1" name="Box1" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox2" name="Box2" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox3" name="Box3" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox4" name="Box4" />
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkBox5" name="Box5" />
</div>
```

Hint: Don't use `document.write()`. Ever. Just forget it exists, there is no reason that would justify using this function.

Comment: Thank you extremely much! Exactly what I was after!